# TypeError: self.records.find(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, odoo

I inherited a Module Account.voucher to my module and I repeatedly performed onchange function to that field and It throws this error on the Web Browser.

```
TypeError: self.records.find(...) is undefined

http: //localhost:8069/web/webclient/js?db=sales:3798
```

I am not a master in JavaScript..

Please help in debugging this Issue

Comment: check for value of self.records,it must be NULL

Comment: show your code that you have done in your module

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.Value(self.SelectedRecord(self.Records().find(x => x.record_code() === record_code));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.